# Auto arrange spacing in tabbing environment

Tags: spacing, tabbing

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=8in, margin=1in, showframe]{geometry}


\newenvironment{myminipage}
{\par\addvspace{2ex}\nopagebreak\noindent\ignorespaces}
{\par\addvspace{2ex}\ignorespacesafterend}

\newenvironment{testenvironment}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{0.75in}\= \hspace*{0.75in}\= \hspace*{0.75in}\= \hspace*{0.75in} \kill
CL1 \> CL2 \> CL3 \> CL3\\
}%
{\end{tabbing}\end{minipage}}%


\begin{document}

\begin{myminipage}
some text\quad\hfill%
\begin{testenvironment}
\end{testenvironment}
\end{myminipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the above `tabbing` definition, the spacing between the columns is fixed. How can I define it such that it shall how much horizontal space it has, and divide the columns evenly?

Comment: Do you really need the tabbing environment?  Why not simply go for hfill or alternatively tabular*?

Comment: Yes, tabbing is essential (even though it is not apparent in this simplistic example).